# Angular httpclient not use absolute url

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I use `Angular 7` and `HttpClient`:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpResponse, HttpRequest, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
```

...

```
this.http.get(this.appConfigService.apiUrl + url, {headers: this.getHeaders(),  params: urlParams} )
```

`this.appConfigService.apiUrl` contain : `https//xxxx-api.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com:80/int/`

But my ajax call is `http://localhost:4200/https//xxxx-api.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com:80/int/meeting`

How to not use `http://localhost:4200/` at the at the beginning of url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a colon in your url after `https`

`https//xxxx-api.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com:80/int/`

should be

`https://xxxx-api.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com:80/int/`

Comment: thank you, I had not seen these two point, I build this url in a service, I will correct.